# php and session redirection errors

Tags: php, mysql, session, dreamweaver, session-cookies

i am creating a login form  and logout with sessions but when i try to login browser display an error ( i think the error is in the logged function )
 anyone can help me because it make me crazy.....
**The page isn't redirecting properly
   Firefox has  that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never detected complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
    cookies.**

## login.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('functions.php');


if(loggedin()){
    header("Location: userarea.php");
    exit();
}


if(isset($_POST['login'])){

  //get data
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];

  if($username && $password){

   $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rememberme  WHERE username = '$username'");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login)){

      $db_password = $row['password'];
      if($password == $db_password)
       $loginok = TRUE;
      else
        $loginok = FALSE;
      if($loginok == TRUE){

         if($rememberme == "on"){
          setcookie("username", $username, time()+7200);



         }else if($rememberme == "")
           $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
         header("Location: userarea.php");
         exit();   


      }else{
       die("incorrect username/password combination");

      }

   }



  }else
    die("please enter a username and password");
    exit();


}


?>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
<p>Username<br />
  <input type="text" name="username" />
</p>
<p> Password<br />
  <input type="password" name="password" />
</p>
<p>
  <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme"> 
  Remember me<br />

  <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in" />
</p>
</form>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

## function.php

```
 <?php
 //session
 session_start();
 // connect to database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("could not connect to database");
 mysql_select_db("rememberme") or die("could not select database");

// login check function

 function loggedin()
{
    $loggedin = false;
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])||isset($_COOKIE['username']))
    {
        $loggedin = TRUE;
    }
    return $loggedin;
}

?>
```

## userarea.php

```
<?php
 //session
 session_start();
 // connect to database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("could not connect to database");
 mysql_select_db("rememberme") or die("could not select database");

// login check function

function loggedin()
{

  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])||isset($_COOKIE['username'])){
    $loggedin = TRUE;
    return $loggedin;  


  }



}

?>
```

Comment: which page you are accessing first.?

Comment: the login.php then the function.php will do the work to redirect me from the login .php to userarea.php but until now this did not successfully happen

Answer (score 0):

You have same function in two files.

```
function loggedin()
```

Try

```
function loggedin()
{
    $loggedin = false;
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])||isset($_COOKIE['username']))
    {
        $loggedin = TRUE;
    }
    return $loggedin;
}
```

If you `if` conditions **not satisfied your function will not return true or false**, so you need to set `initial` value to `false` and then **overwrite** it if `if condition` satisfied.

**Login.php**

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];

    if($username && $password)
    {
        $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rememberme WHERE username = '".$username."'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login))
        {
            $db_password = $row['password'];
            if($password == $db_password)
                $loginok = TRUE;
            else
                $loginok = FALSE;
            if($loginok == TRUE)
            {
                if($rememberme == "on")
                {
                    setcookie("username", $username, time()+7200);
                }
                else if($rememberme == "")
                {
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    header("Location: userarea.php");
                    exit();   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                die("incorrect username/password combination");
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        die("please enter a username and password");
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <p>Username<br />
        <input type="text" name="username" />
    </p>
    <p>Password<br />
        <input type="password" name="password" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme"> 
        Remember me<br />
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in" />
    </p>
</form>
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db("rememberme") or die("could not select database");

// login check function

if(loggedin())
{
    header("Location: userarea.php");
    exit();
}

function loggedin()
{
    $loggedin = false;
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])||isset($_COOKIE['username']))
    {
        $loggedin = TRUE;
    }
    return $loggedin;
}

?>
```

**userarea.php**

```
<?php
    require_once "functions.php";
    echo "after login";
?>
```

Comment: @user2097286 so please now update your question with latest code so i can help better.

Comment: @user2097286 right below question there is share and edit link use it

Comment: so anyone have a solution ??

Comment: @user2097286 see i have modified some of the code please check it otherwise its working

Comment: still give me the same error message                                The page isn't redirecting properly                                   Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.                       This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
    cookies.     plzz help me how  the hell to fix this error

Comment: @user2097286 make sure wamp server is running...clear browser cookies and clear cache and try...is there .htaccess file..??

Comment: the wmap server is running and i cleared the browser cookies and the cash and still having the same  annoying error ....

Comment: @user2097286 is there any .htaccess file..??

Comment: @user2097286 i told you every possible error solution and you don't have reputation so i can't add you in chat...

Comment: @user2097286 copy paste all of the updated code from my answer and then try...just replace database connection setting accordingly.

Comment: mmm thanks for your help  i do not know  how to fix it i will search other or any forums that i will find on it a solution to my problem    thank you again

Comment: no change still the same error how come it work with you but not working with me what i have to do it is a very important and required action to do

Comment: @devleb check for the php version as mysql_* is deprecated from now...then as i told check for .htaccess file...clear cache and cookies...and more pls check for other code inside this three file...have you posted all the code inside this files..??? pls answer all this questions\